# What parts of my application can I access and use during a shutdown hook execution?

Tags: java, runtime, shutdown-hook

I am trying to understand when a shutdown hook executes. Is it before or after any part of my application has been stopped? Since my shutdown hook code will be running in a freshly created thread, can I access other non-shutdown-hook threads from it? Or they might be stopped/killed by the exiting JVM?

Of course I am assuming the the JVM is exiting due to an exception and not due to a unrecoverable crash which would not execute the shutdown hooks anyways.

Comment: You access objects, not threads. As long as you have a reference to them, you can use them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right, but I would like to receive a callback from another thread for example.

Comment: There are no reliable guarantees for shutdown hooks. The only safe assumption is that all other threads are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadoc documentation of `Runtime#addShutdownHook`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)):

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

From the first event, you shouldn't expect that threads are still alive when the shutdown hook is running (except for daemon threads).

From the same page:

> Note that daemon threads will continue to run during the shutdown sequence, as will non-daemon threads if shutdown was initiated by invoking the `exit` method.

When the program terminates due to an exception, all threads will eventually die, which will *then*  the shutdown hook.

Comment: I did not get it. So will my daemon thread be running during a shutdown hook assuming it was not the one that threw the exception? Or not? Undefined?

Comment: @TraderJenny Yes a daemon thread will be running during the shutdown hook, unless of course it is manually finished before the shutdown hook runs.